# "a float is required" error

Tags: python, function

I already looked at many questions posted here but couldn't find an answer. This is the snippet of my code that is causing problems:

the constant:

```
antvelocity=float(10) #pixels per frame
```

another part of the code(randir() is a global function):

```
def randir():
    n=float(random.randint(0,8))
    ang=(n*math.pi)/4
```

The ant class:

```
class Ant:
    antx=0
    anty=0
    id=0

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id
    def draw(self):
        SCREEN.blit(antimg,(self.antx,self.anty))
    def seek(self):
        randang=randir()
        velx=math.floor(float(antvelocity)*float(math.cos(randang)))
        vely=math.floor(float(antvelocity)*float(math.sin(randang)))
        self.antx=self.antx+velx
        self.anty=self.anty+velx
        self.draw()
        pygame.display.update()

        #Handling code for seeking
    def carry(self):
        pass
        #Handling code for carrying leaf
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++ERROR+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acisace/Python Projects/Gathering/gather.py", line 101, in <module>
    ant1.seek()
  File "/home/acisace/Python Projects/Gathering/gather.py", line 64, in seek
    velx=math.floor(float(antvelocity)*float(math.cos(randang)))
TypeError: a float is required
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Please help me rectify this problem

---

Thanks everyone. Couldn't believe I missed that.

Comment: What Python are you using?

Comment: How are you accessing `antvelocity` inside the class

Comment: Your `randir()` function doesn't seem to be returning anything, although you seem to expect it to return something - `randang=randir()`

Comment: @Kamehameha How about posting your answer as answer? :-)

Comment: Side note - how much easier would it be to debug the code if you split the 1 big line `velx=math.floor(float(antvelocity)*float(math.cos(randang)))` into 3 separate lines.

Comment: @Sloth Too late too late ;)

Comment: @Kamehameha There goes some easy rep... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `randir()` function doesn't *return* anything:

```
def randir():
    n=float(random.randint(0,8))
    ang=(n*math.pi)/4
```

so `None` is returned instead:

```
>>> import random, math
>>> def randir():
...     n=float(random.randint(0,8))
...     ang=(n*math.pi)/4
... 
>>> randir()
>>> randir() is None
True
```

You are then passing that `None` value to `math.cos()`:

```
math.cos(randang)
```

which throws your error:

```
>>> math.cos(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

You'll have to add a `return` statement to the function if you want to fix that:

```
def randir():
    n=float(random.randint(0,8))
    ang=(n*math.pi)/4
    return ang
```

Answer (score 1):

```
randang=randir()
velx=math.floor(float(antvelocity)*float(math.cos(randang)))
```

Since it's the second line of that snippet that appears to be the issue, the most likely cause is `randang` since `float()` wouldn't *require* a float and, if you do something silly like `float('a')`, you get a different error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: a

And indeed, the definition for `randir` shows why:

```
def randir():
    n=float(random.randint(0,8))
    ang=(n*math.pi)/4
```

It's not specifically returning *anything,* meaning that you'll get `None`.

See, as a simpler example, the following transcript:

```
>>> def nothing():
...     pass
...

>>> print nothing()
None

>>> import math
>>> print math.cos(nothing())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

You need to return a float (or something that can *become* a float) from your `randir()` function:

```
>>> def nothing():
...     return 0.5
...

>>> print nothing()
0.5

>>> import math
>>> print math.cos(nothing())
0.87758256189
```

In your case, the function should probably be:

```
def randir():
    n = float(random.randint(0,8))
    ang = (n * math.pi) / 4
    return ang
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `randir` is returning `None`, which is not a float. (If you don't specify a return value in any given function, it'll return `None` by default.) Then you pass the result (stored in `randang`) to `cos`, which is defined for floats only. Just add:

```
return ang
```

to the end of `randir`.